# Can I get "ad_impression" and "ad_click" from BigQuery linked with Firebase analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, admob

I use Firebase analytics and AdMob to gather my mobile app events, and link Firebase analytics with BigQuery.
Then I try to get "ad_impression" and "ad_click" events from BigQuery, but there are no those event name records.

questions are

1. Are there any ways to get those events from BigQuery linked with Firebase analytics?
2. Are there any other ways to get those events paired with mobile ad id?

#### I did

I checked there are no those events by a such query

```
SELECT
    event.name   
FROM
    `{MyAppDataSet}.app_events_*`,
    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event   
WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20180624" AND "20180628" 
    AND event.name LIKE "ad_%"   
GROUP BY
    event.name;
```

and result json.(Can get only "ad_reward" event);

```
{"name":"ad_reward"}
```

#### I checked

- Firebase analytics and AdMob are linked.
- Firebase analytics and BigQuery are linked.
- "ad_impression" and "ad_click" are shown in Firebase analytics console.
- Can get other events from BigQuery.
- I linked those services over 1 week ago.
- Over thousand analytics events / day are sent.

Comment: My name is Ed and I'm currently the product manager behind the AdMob+Firebase integration. Unfortunately, there's currently no way of accessing the ad_click or ad_impression events from BigQuery. Would you mind describing what kind of analysis you would like to do if you did have access to these events?

Comment: I'm developing games which are monetized by showing ads.So I wan't to analyze histogram of ad impressions par user, median of ads clicks par user, hourly average ad impressions, and so on.

Comment: @zilla I'm trying to analyze the data in order to detect posible ad clicks abusers. My admob account is currently limited by invalid traffic related matters. Is there any way I can get where are the malicious clicks coming from?

Comment: AFAIK, ad_clicks and ad_impressions are still unaccessible from BigQuery. There, unfortunately, aren't good ways of better understanding malicious clicks; however, you can always attempt to go through the appeals process.

Comment: @zilla, I was trying to create a histogram with the distribution of the percentage of users who watched the ad at least 1 time, at least 2 times, and so on. Is there any way to create that histogram using Admob/Firebase, or should I wait for ad_impression events to appear in BigQuery?